# Why is the name of Athens (Athenae) plural?

Tags: vocabulary

The Latin word for Athens, *Athenae*, is plural. Why is this?

Comment: I don't believe a satisfactory answer has ever been found, but see [Smyth 1005](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Asmythp%3D1005): "Names of towns and parts of the body are sometimes plural: Ἀθῆναι Athens, Θῆβαι Thebes, στήθη and στέρνα breast (chiefly poetic). The name of the inhabitants is often used for the name of a city: Δελφοί D. 5.25."

Comment: @cmw So it is kind of an anomaly then, that has no regular explanation?

Comment: People have posited various reasons, but *Athenae* isn't an anomaly. Many cities (Syracusae, Thebae, Veii) were plural, not just Athens.

Comment: @cmw I mean anomaly in the sense that it is unexplained, not in that it is unique.

Comment: There are explanations, just none that have become consensus.

Comment: Most prominent  The  Peloponnesus (auch: Peloponnese, Peloponnesos) [GEOG.]  
der   (fachspr.: die) Peloponnes  that finally in German with a quite different gender system got its regular Greek genus. Generally names of places, rivers, islands are constant over many changes of the populations language, except by brute force sometimes. Eg Constantinople was renamed to 'eis tin poly' (Greek: into the town) in order to end the use of the Greek name, accomplished  by a multilingual officer, renamed Atatürk later.